# SetParent() (win32)

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

Any ideas how to use SetParent()?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
fhWnd = FindWindow(_T("Notepad"), NULL);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST , _T("test"), _T("test"),
        WS_POPUP,
        20, 20, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

 SetParent(hWnd, fhWnd);

 DWORD style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
 style = style & ~(WS_POPUP);
 style = style | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS;
 SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
 SetWindowLong(fhWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(fhWnd, GWL_STYLE) | WS_CLIPCHILDREN);
```

With the above code I have to move the parent window out of the screen and back in again in order to see what's draw on the child window.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Cross-process parenting is extremely difficult and requires cooperation between the two processes. That does not appear to be the case here. (Notepad has no idea that you are playing parenting games, so it does not do the appropriate coordination.) Try again but use another program you wrote instead of Notepad.

Comment: much easier if you just use a multiline editbox and make the menus yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, see link below, the window style should be changed before calling SetParent().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent?devlangs=cpp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WINUSER%252FSetParent)%3Bk(SetParent)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue

After SetParent() the UISTATE should be updated for the Child and Parent. I'm still figuring this one out. I will update when I have success.

Optional for your code after SetParent()

```
// Now update the UIState for the child and the parent
WPARAM uistate_child  = LOWORD(UIS_INITIALIZE) + HIWORD(UISF_ACTIVE);
WPARAM uistate_parent = LOWORD(UIS_INITIALIZE) + HIWORD(UISF_ACTIVE);

LRESULT lresult_child = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, uistate_child, (LPARAM)0);

LRESULT lresult_parent = SendMessage(fhWnd, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, uistate_parent, (LPARAM)0);

if (lresult_child != 0) { printf("\n\n Child -> Change UI State Error %i", GetLastError() ); }

if (lresult_parent != 0) { printf("\n\n Parent -> Change UI State Error %i", GetLastError() ); }
```